# why is data based url containing document.domain alert box empty?

Tags: javascript, base64, xss, alert, base64url

I insert a page containing the following content

```
<a href="data:text/html;base64,PGlmcmFtZSBzcmM9ImphdmFzY3JpcHQ6ZG9jdW1lbnQuZG9tYWluKSI+PC9pZnJhbWU+">test</a>
```

But when i click on the link it shows me an empty alert box. Why is document.domain not working?

The alert box should contain my domain but it's empty, do you know what is that due to?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. `document.domain` is not in the code you posted. We have no way of knowing what is wrong without more code.

Comment: That url decodes to `<iframe src="javascript:document.domain)"></iframe>`.  What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: @ScottSauyet,
I'm trying to understand why the alert box is empty instead of containing my document.domain value

Comment: @Chipster, it's base64 encoded...

Comment: Maybe it's missing the `(`? Or it doesn't need the `)`?

Comment: There is no `alert` statement in there, just `javascript:document.domain`.

Comment: @Chipster, yeah it needs the (), i adjusted it to <iframe src="javascript:alert(document.domain)"></iframe> and base64 encoded it -
It still show an empty alert box thou....

Comment: @ScottSauyet Maybe he doesn't mean alert alert, but possibly the iframe by "alert".

Comment: @JyoskNatalm Perhaps could you post some relevant code for `document.domain()`?

Comment: If i used <iframe src="javascript:alert(1)"></iframe>  or <iframe src="javascript:alert('test')"></iframe> it works perfectly but with document.domain and document.cookie the alert box is empty.

Comment: If you try ``<iframe src="javascript:alert(`"${document.domain}"`)"></iframe>``, it might show whether your domain is an empty string.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I'm passing this data value as post request redirect and it shows an empty string instead of previous domain.

Comment: Perhaps I'm confused, but I don't see how you're expecting any sort of document.domain when your source is a `data:` url.  Are you expecting it to share the domain of the document containing that anchor (`<a...>`) element?

Comment: @ScottSauyet,
I don't know if still possible, but i'm expecting that after clicking the link containing my data: url the alert box show my current document domain. I have uploaded the html page in my domain but the alert box is empty.

Comment: A `data:` uri is stand-alone.  It shouldn't, as I understand it, ever have a domain.